# Get Total of NgFor item Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I have an leave array with leave counts of different leave types, I have to return the total of every leave types

```
array = {
    "Jan 2021": [
        {
            "WFH": 17.5
        },
        {
            "CL": 3.5
        }
    ],
    "Feb 2021": [
        {
            "WFH": 19.5
        },
        {
            "CL": 2.5
        }
    ],
    "Mar 2021": [
        {
            "WFH": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my html file:

```
<table class="table table-statitics2 table-bordered" aria-label="Leave">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="casual">CL</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="earned">EL</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody *ngIf="leaves">
                                <tr *ngFor="let item of leaves | keyvalue : keepOriginalOrder">
                                    <td class="date">{{item.key}}</td>
                                    <td>{{getMonthyItem(item.value, "CL")}}</td>
                                    <td>{{getMonthyItem(item.value, "EL")}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                  <th colspan="2" class="text-center text-danger" scope="row">Total</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Total of CL</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Total of EL</th>
                                </tr>
                              </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

this is my function to return Leave Count

```
getMonthyItem(items, object)
  {
    let result = '';
    items.forEach(element => {
      if(Object.keys(element) == object)
      {
        result  = element[object];
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

How can I return total of every leave types on footer section of table, also is there any simple way to return leave counts directly on html page without the function, that have used.

Expected result is,

|  | **CL** | **WFH** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2021 | 3.5 | 17.5 |
| Feb 2021 | 2.5 | 19.5 |
| Mar 2021 | 1 | 13 |
| **Total** | **7** | **50** |

Thanks............................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: what is value of leaves array that you have used on tbody

Comment: value will be leave types.

Comment: @sadiquemohammed check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-statitics2 table-bordered" aria-label="Leave">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="casual">CL</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="earned">EL</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody *ngIf="leaves">
                                <tr *ngFor="let item of leaves | keyvalue : keepOriginalOrder">
                                    <td class="date">{{item.key}}</td>
                                    <td>{{getMonthyItem(item.value, "CL")}}</td>
                                    <td>{{getMonthyItem(item.value, "EL")}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                  <th colspan="2" class="text-center text-danger" scope="row">Total</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Total of CL</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Total of EL</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                   <td>total('CL')</td>
                                   <td>total('EL')</td>
                                </tr>
                              </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

and then in your .ts function define a new function. As I see you already keep as field the `leaves` which contains all the information. So it would be

```
public total (type: string): number {
   let sum = 0;
   Object.keys(this.leaves).forEach(key => {
       this.leaves[key].forEach(element => {
            sum = sum + (element[type] ? element[type] : 0);
          });
   });
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `leave[key][type]` is undefined.

Comment: Actually the issue is `this.leaves[key][type]` returns the key's not values, so we are trying to sum the key's instead of the values.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about it is to calculate the total in a function and add an extra row manually with the data in:

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-statitics2 table-bordered" aria-label="Leave">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="casual">CL</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="earned">EL</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody *ngIf="leaves">
                                <tr *ngFor="let item of leaves | keyvalue : keepOriginalOrder">
                                    <td class="date">{{item.key}}</td>
                                    <td>{{getMonthyItem(item.value, "CL")}}</td>
                                    <td>{{getMonthyItem(item.value, "EL")}}</td>
                                </tr>
<tr>
<td class="date">Total</td>
<td>{{total(leaves, "CL")}}</td>
<td>{{total(leaves, "WFH")}}</td>
</tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                  <th colspan="2" class="text-center text-danger" scope="row">Total</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Total of CL</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Total of EL</th>
                                </tr>
                              </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Function:

```
total(items, object)
  {
    let result = 0;
    items.forEach(x => {
      if(Object.keys(x) == object)
      {
        result  = result + x[object];
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: The `item.value` will be undefined of outside first <tr> tag

Comment: I've edited it since, you need to put in the name of your array where I have written leaves